# How do I make the global type context variable in flutter?

Tags: dart, flutter

I just figured out some problem when I tried to navigate from one page to the other in flutter. The **Navigation.push** method requires the context variable and I need reference to the context for navigating.

```
Widget navBox(Color aColor, double left, double top, Icon icon,String action, Route route) {
  return Positioned (
        left: left,
        top: top,
        child: InkWell(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
            onTap: () {
              Navigator.push(context, route);
            },
            child: new Container(
            height: 220.0,
            width: 220.0,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: aColor,
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
            ),
            child: Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(40.0),
                child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: <Widget>[
                  icon,
                  new Text(action, style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 20.0, fontFamily: 'Oxygen')),
                ],
              ),
            ),
           ),
          ),
        );
}
```

I expected to navigate to the other page by the call of this function with proper route defined.

**I got the error like:**

The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown while handling a gesture

The method 'ancestorStateOfType' was called on null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add a `context` parameter to the method's signature. But also have in mind that methods shouldn't have so many parameters, because it makes them harder to use.

Comment: upvote, but six params is not bad, compare it to https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/gesture_detector.dart#L162 for example ;-) i know they are optional but still `Render*` classes use dozens of params

Answer (score 0):

Wrapping the InkWell with the new Builder or the Material widget solves the problem.

**Here's the snippet on how I solved the problem:**

```
child: new Container(
            height: 220.0,
            width: 220.0,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: aColor,
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
            ),
            child: new Builder(
              builder: (context) => InkWell(
                onTap: () {
                  Navigator.push(context,
                                 MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => GetData()),);
                },
                child: Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(40.0),
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        icon,
                        new Text(action, style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 20.0, fontFamily: 'Oxygen')),
                ],
              ),
            ),
              ),
            ),
           ),
```

I am only listing the Container widget of the function. So rest of them could be figured out by yourself.